# Binding Object Data Source Update Parameters to Business Entity

Tags: objectdatasource

I have a GridView on my ASP.net website which is bound to the Tasks entity.The Task entity is
generated by the entity framework:

```
class Task
{
   int    TaskID;
   string TaskName;
   string TaskDescription;
   int    TaskWeightage;
}
```

I'm trying to insert Task in GridView using an object Data source. I've defined the InsertParameters for object data source as:
TaskID,TaskName,TaskDescription,TaskWeightage.

I've declared the Insert method for the object data source as:

```
public bool AddTask(Task t)
{}
```

I would like the Object Data source to construct the Task Object from the Insert Parameters and then call the Insert method.How can I acheive this?